# Problem with duplicates, when i click add button 2 times the duplicates value is 3 not 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When i click button add, he push the item to the items array the count should be 2 not 3, but he gives me 3

1 click same button: console

{name: "Margherita", price: 10, ingredients: "Manitoba flour 200 g, Water

300 ml, Salt up to 10 g, Extra virgin olive oil 35 g, Tomato pulp 500 g",

image: "../assets/img/pizza-margherita.png"}

item.service.ts:23 -1

item.service.ts:35 else

item.service.ts:38

[{…}]

0: {name: "Margherita", counter: 1, price: 10}

length: 1

**proto**: Array(0)

2 click same button: console

{name: "Margherita", price: 10, ingredients: "Manitoba flour 200 g, Water

300 ml, Salt up to 10 g, Extra virgin olive oil 35 g, Tomato pulp 500 g",

image: "../assets/img/pizza-margherita.png"}

item.service.ts:23 0

item.service.ts:27 if

item.service.ts:21

{name: "Margherita", price: 10, ingredients: "Manitoba flour 200 g, Water

300 ml, Salt up to 10 g, Extra virgin olive oil 35 g, Tomato pulp 500 g",

image: "../assets/img/pizza-margherita.png"}

item.service.ts:23 0

item.service.ts:27 if

item.service.ts:38

[{…}]

0: {name: "Margherita", counter: 3, price: 30}

length: 1

**proto**: Array(0)    items = [];

```
newArray: Cart[] = [];

constructor() { }

saveToLocal(element) { // Save pizza to local Storage
  this.items.push(element);
  this.items = this.items.sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : -1); 

  this.items.forEach(item => {

    console.log(element);
    const index = this.newArray.findIndex(x => x.name === item.name); 
    console.log(index);

    if (index > -1) {
      this.newArray[index].counter++;
      this.newArray[index].price += item.price;
      console.log('if');
    } else {
      const a = {
        name: item.name,
        counter: 1,
        price: item.price
      };

      this.newArray.push(a);
      console.log('else');
    }
  });

  console.log(this.newArray);
  localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(this.newArray)); 
}
```

Comment: How do you bind the onclick event?

Comment: From another component, which has the button that is linked to the element to be added to the array

Comment: Please show the code for it.

Comment: In practice when I click the button with which element directly accesses the saveToLocal () function

Comment: This is the code for button click public addToCart(pizza: Pizza) {
    this.itemService.saveToLocal(pizza);
  }

Comment: From your posted code, whenever you click, you add 1 item to array. There is no issue with it. That's why I suspect that something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: The html for the button <button class="btn-pizza-cart" (click)="addToCart(pizza)">Add to
          cart</button>

Comment: I do not think so. The problem is here on that code, because in the for loop it sees every element present in newArray I think it gives me problems. I used this code in another Angular component and it worked. Only in this component does it not work